# Can I display a FlowDocument (or equivalent) on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, flowdocument

I've got a use case where I'd like to display multiple html fragments within a single UI. My first attempt was to use a number of webbrowser controls and [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx). I didn't really like the way that looked and having multiple of those controls does not seem to work well at all (slow load time, flickering and even crashes).

Attempt #2 is to convert the html fragment into a FlowDocument. After I get that conversion working by porting [this code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx) to WP7. So now I've got some text that I can load into a FlowDocument but then I'm all like "hey where's the FlowDocument?" It looks like FlowDocument didn't make the cut for WP7 though some System.Windows.Documents types that did (FontSource, Glyphs, Inline, InlineCollection, LineBreak, Run)

I'd rather not convert the html in to raw text as I'd like to paragraphs and hyperlinks. Is there a way to present a flowdocument or something like it on WP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TextBlock` (or a `RichTextBox` if you use Mango) with `Run` and `HyperLink` elements inside. That's the only form of FlowDocument there is available for Windows Phone.

Example:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Hello" Foreground="Yellow" />
    <Run Text=" " />
    <Run Text="World" Foreground="Orange" />
</TextBlock>
```

You can read more in [this article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control)